# Float must be a string or a number?

Tags: python, type-conversion, text-files

I have a very simple program. The code:

```
money = open("money.txt", "r")
moneyx = float(money)
print(moneyx)
```

The text file, money.txt, contains only this:

```
0.00
```

The error message I receive is:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

It is most likely a simple mistake. Any advice? I am using Python 3.3.3.

Comment: Try: `moneyx = float(money.read().strip())`, Actually there may be a `\n` character, so internally it may look like `0.00\n` and when you try `float("0.0\n")` it raises an error.

Comment: `money` is a file, not the content of the file. Try `float(money.read())`

Comment: @ZdaR, nope, newlines and whitespace are handled by float

Comment: `money` is a file handle, thus it can not be casted to a float. Read the file first.

Comment: Then what maybe the possible reason behind the error ? @PadraicCunningham

Comment: @ZdaR, f is a file object not a string or a float

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`money` is a [`file` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects), *not* the content of the file. To get the content, you have to `read` the file. If the entire file contains just that one number, then [`read()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.read) is all you need.

```
moneyx = float(money.read())
```

Otherwise you might want to use [`readline()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readline) to read a single line or even try the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module for more complex files.

Also, don't forget to [`close()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.close) the file when you are done, or use the `with` keyword to have it closed automatically.

```
with open("money.txt") as money:
    moneyx = float(money.read())
print(moneyx)
```

Answer (score 4):

Money is a file, not a string, therefore you cannot convert a whole file to a float. Instead you can do something like this, where you read the whole file into a list, where each line is an item in the list. You would loop through and convert it that way.

```
money = open("money.txt", "r")
lines = money.readlines()
for l in lines:
   moneyx = float(l)
   print(moneyx)
```

Comment: you don't need to use readlines, there is no point building a list to throw it away

Answer (score 0):

It's better practice to use "with" when opening a file in python. This way the file is implicitly closed after the operation is done

```
with open("money.txt", "r") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    for line in content:
        print float(line)
```

Comment: It is also better practice not to call readlines unless you want a list